# Handing Avro messages based on Apache Beam KafkaIO python SDK

Tags: python, apache-beam, apache-beam-kafkaio

I am currently trying to read the message as ByteDeserializer similar to the following example [KafkaIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/kafkataxi/kafka_taxi.py). My test setup is as follows:

Option 1:
Configured to use --runner=PortableRunner

Option 2:
start the local flink job server,

```
docker run --net=host apache/beam_flink1.10_job_server:latest
```

Publish test kafka avro messages

Pipeline args is defined as,

```
pipeline_args = ['--runner', 'FlinkRunner',
                 '--job_endpoint', 'localhost:8099',
                 '--environment_type', 'LOOPBACK',
                 '--flink_version', '1.10',
                 '--flink_master', 'localhost:8081']
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args, save_main_session=True,streaming=True)
```

Pipeline setup,

```
_ = (pipeline | ReadFromKafka(
                consumer_config= {'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092'},
                topic = ['beam-test-topic'])
              | beam.Flatmap(lambda kv: log_topic_contents(kv[1])))
```

when I execute the pipeline, the default expansion service SDK image (apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.29.0) is used and the job is submitted to the flink job server. The flink job server fails with a message "Failed to submit JobGraph" and "Rest endpoint shutdown".

Do I miss out any runtime configuration with the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-language transforms are currently not supported for 'LOOPBACK' environment type. Can you retry with the 'DOCKER' type ?